# Create Context Menu on QPushButton in QT Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I've been designing a Python GUI for my app and I wanted to know how does one add a context menu on a QPushButton when clicking on it (should appear in the right).

I right clicked on the qpushbutton and changed ContextMenuPolicy to "CustomContextMenu" but not sure what do do next.